# $\{\vec{a}, \vec{b}\}$ is linearly independent then $\{4\vec{a}-\vec{b}, 2\vec{a}+3\vec{b}\}$ is linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

if $\{\vec{a}, \vec{b}\}$ is linearly independent how would you determine if 
$\{4\vec{a}-\vec{b}, 2\vec{a}+3\vec{b}\}$ is linearly independent

I have have managed to show through manipulation that
for $C_1, C_2 \in \Bbb{R}$
$(4C_1+C_2)\vec{a}+(3C_2-C_1)\vec{b}=\vec{0}$ Is it enough to say that since $\{\vec{a}, \vec{b}\}$ is linearly independent then as a result since $(4C_1+C_2),(3C_2-C_1)\in \Bbb{R}$ then $\{4\vec{a}-\vec{b}, 2\vec{a}+3\vec{b}\}$ is linearly independent?

Comment: With $(4C_1+C_2)\vec{a}+(3C_2-C_1)\vec{b}=\vec{0}$ you got something that contradicts one of your initial assumptions that $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{a}$ are linearly independent (linear independence happens precisely when you can find a linear combination that is $\vec{0}$). Since assuming that the vectors in question are linearly dependent lead to this contradiction, then it follows that they in fact are linearly independent (proven by contradiction)

Comment: Should it be $(4C_1+2C_2)\vec{a}?$

Answer (score 2):

Because $$4\cdot3-2\cdot(-1)\neq0.$$

Comment: What does that mean exactly?

Comment: I calculated some determinant.

Comment: what about without determinants?

Comment: Just write that they depend and solve the system. You'll got that all coefficients they are equal to $0$.

Answer (score 2):

$\begin{pmatrix} 
a  \\
b  
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 
4 & -1 \\
2 & 3 
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 
a  \\
b  
\end{pmatrix}$ and \begin{pmatrix} 
4 & -1 \\
2 &  3 
\end{pmatrix} is invertible

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, but you need to say more and be clear about why you are concluding linear independence. (I think) what you did was begin by assuming

$$
C_1(4a - b) + C_2(2a + 3b) = 0
$$

for some $C_1,C_2 \in \mathbb{R}$. Now, your goal is to show that $C_1 = C_2 = 0$ (Why?). You can rearrange the above equation to get

$$
(4C_1 + 2C_2)a + (3C_2 - C_1)b = 0
$$

Because $a$ and $b$ are linearly independent we conclude $4C_1 + 2C_2 = 0$ and $3C_2 - C_1 = 0$. From this, what do you conclude about $C_1$ and $C_2$. And what does that mean in the context of your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose 
$(4c_1 + c_2)a + (-c_1 + 3c_2)b = 0$

then:

$4c_1 + c_2 = 0\\
-c_1 + 3c_2 = 0$

This system has a unique solution, $c_1= c_2 = 0$

If the only solution is the trivial solution, your vectors are independent.